# ソケットコネクション常時接続したい、切断時は再接続したい。

Tags: c#, network, socket

お世話になります。
TCPソケットについての質問です。
レスポンス速度確保のため、ソケットのコネクションを常時接続にしたままで処理を行い、何らかの原因で、コネクションが切断された場合、再接続を行うようにしたいのですが、実現可能でしょうか？クライアントはWindows10 C#、サーバーは未定です。
再接続時のサーバー再起動も避けたいです。

Answer (score 1):

[TCP Keep Alive](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96#TCP%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96)は名前の通り接続を持続させるものとしてよく知られています。実はそれだけでなく、切断検出にも使えます。
C#であれば[Socket.SetSocketOptionメソッド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/e160993d(v=vs.110).aspx)で設定できます。

> 再接続時のサーバー再起動も避けたいです。

これはサーバーの実装次第であり、クライアントでは制御できません。

---

> Keep Aliveは、Linuxにも実装されていますでしょうか？

Linuxに限らずほぼ全ての通信機器で実装されています。（そうでないと応答も受け取れないためKeep Aliveを有効にした瞬間、無応答で切断扱いされてしまいます。）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。Technetでは、大変お世話になっております。Keep Aliveは、Linuxにも実装されていますでしょうか？